Doubt on general solution of PDE
I have the PDE
$$
\alpha^2 \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2} + \beta^2 \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}=0
$$
I want to find the general solution using the change of variables
$$
\begin{cases}   
  &\psi = \beta x + \alpha y \\
  &\eta = \beta x + i \alpha y \\
\end{cases}
$$
Therefore I get the PDE
$$
2 \alpha^2 \beta^2 \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial \psi^2}=0 \implies \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial \psi^2}=0
$$
Solving it with reiterated integration we call $W= \frac{\partial z}{\partial \psi}$ so we can write the PDE as
$$
\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial \psi^2} =
\frac{\partial W}{\partial \psi} =  
0
$$
that has general solution $W(\psi,\eta) = f(\eta)$ with $f$ an arbitrary function because W doesn't depend on $\psi$. Finally, there only rests to find the general solution of
$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial \psi} = f(\eta)
$$
So doing the integration
$$ 
\int \frac{\partial z}{\partial \psi} d\psi =
\int f(\eta) d\psi = F(\eta,\psi) + H(\eta)
$$
where $F$ is the primitive of $f$ and $H$ is an arbitrary function.
My question is if I can write $F(\eta,\psi) + H(\eta) = G(\eta) + I(\psi)$ with $G$ and $I$ arbitrary functions and if so, why?
Thanks in advance, best regards!

When solving a PDE, it’s always important to stare the domain you want for the solution.

Sure @Deane, with $\alpha, \beta \neq 0$ I think we can choose any domain we like

By the way, you wrote the PDE without an =.

After the change of variable, the solution is a harmonic function with respect to the new variables. This is always the real part of a holomorphic function on some subdomain of $\mathbb{C}$.
